# angular-meteor patterns for handling multiple reactive variables efficiently

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm playing with `angular-meteor` and still trying to understand how to use 3-way binding. How do I run a method that checks multiple 'reactive' variables?

For example, the `setVisibleLocation()` method below would need to be re-run if any of the following values changed, `event.setting.isPublic, event.participantIds, event.location, event.address, event.neighborhood, Meteor.userId()`. The last few might not need to update reactively - a page reload might be acceptable.

```
showExactLocation = (event, userId) ->
  return true if event.setting.isPublic
  return true if userId == event.ownerId
  return true if event.participantIds && ~event.participantIds.indexOf(userId)
  return false

setVisibleLocation = (event, userId) ->
  userId ?= Meteor.userId()
  if showExactLocation(event, userId)
    event.visible = {
      address: event.address
      marker: event.location
    }
  else
    event.visible = {
      address: event.neighborhood
      marker: utils.maskLatLon(event.location, event.title)
    }
  return event
```

What are the more efficient patterns for handling this? I can think of a few options.

```
this.autorun ()=>
  this.getReactively('event', true)
  setVisibleLocation(this.event)
  // plus any number of other methods that might need to update
  // based on changes to this.event properties
```

or

```
this.autorun ()=>
  this.getReactively('event.setting.isPublic')
  this.getReactively('event.location')
  this.getCollectionReactively('event.participantIds')
  this.getReactively('event.address')
  this.getReactively('event.neighborhood')
  setVisibleLocation(this.event)
this.autorun ()=>
  // plus any number of other combination of reactive properties 
  // and methods that need to be rerun
```

Is a deep watch advisable if `event` has a lot of properties to check?

Comment: You can use the second parameter of getReactively to do deep watch - this.getReactively('event', true)